# Tantalum capacitors in synchronous DC/DC converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I'm designing a synchronous DC/DC converter with discrete components for a project. The overall power supply, which I'll refer to as the DC bus, is 5V. I wanted to know if it's advisable to use a tantalum capacitor in the DC bus of the circuit to mitigate the noise generated by the converter. The switching frequency is 100kHz

Comment: Is this cap on the output?  You have to have enough filtering (inductors & caps) on the output to reduce the ripple frequency to whatever you load requires.

Comment: What would be the reason to use a tantalum cap; why do you consider a tantalum?

Comment: What kind of converter? A buck will want ceramics on the input. A boost will want them on the output for their tighter layout and resulting lower ESL capabilities. You can use Ta as bulk cap on input/output but as others have put it: their only advantage vs Al electrolytic or ceramic ones is density..If you don't require the density, don't use Ta, I guess.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not necessary to use a tantalum. Generally, for the input side ceramic capacitors are sufficient, combined with bulk electrolytic or Al-polymer if needed to handle load transients.

The DC-DC output cap type will depend on what the regulator expects for the cap Equivalent Series Resistance, or ESR. Check the data sheet. Still, this will be an electrolytic, Al-polymer or MLCC.

These days, there's very, very few cases where tantalum caps are a go-to choice, and should be avoided as tantalum is a conflict mineral. They do have better long-term stability than electrolytic, and are more dense than MLCCs. That said, MLCC's are preferred in most applications, with advances in density making them viable tantalum replacements for dense devices like mobile handsets. Al-polymer caps offer similar benefits to tantalum when larger values are needed.

Comment: Note that aluminum electrolytics are expressly prohibited in many hi-rel applications.

Comment: In addition to being a conflict mineral, tantalum caps are notorious for their tendency to fail in quite spectacular manners, frequently involving flame. When you refer to polymer capacitors, do you mean aluminum-polymer or tantalum-polymer? Both do exist.

Comment: Your answer implies the OP is building a buck, although this is not stated explicitly.